# Object #<Object> has no method 'User'

Tags: javascript, object, methods, meteor

everyone. I have a problem with my code and Meteor 0.9.4

Here is my code:

Server/publications.js

```
Meteor.publish('getUsers', function () {
    var loggedInUser = Meteor.User();

    if (Roles.userIsInRole(loggedInUser, ['admin'])) {     
        return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {
            _id: 1,
            emails: 1,
            roles: 1
        }});
    }

    this.stop();
    return;
});
```

Lib/router.js

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('dashboardUsers', {
        layoutTemplate: 'dashboardLayout',   
        path: "/dashboard/users",
        waitOn: function() {
            return Meteor.subscribe('getUsers');
        }
    });    
});
```

When I run meteor app, I have the following error:

```
=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
I20141019-18:21:50.827(4)? Exception from sub 8CRiG3Jmdv4mohPhd TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'User'
I20141019-18:21:50.949(4)?     at null._handler (app/server/publications.js:3:31)
I20141019-18:21:50.950(4)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1594)
I20141019-18:21:50.950(4)?     at _.extend._runHandler (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:943)
I20141019-18:21:50.950(4)?     at _.extend._startSubscription (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:769)
I20141019-18:21:50.951(4)?     at _.extend.protocol_handlers.sub (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:582)
I20141019-18:21:50.951(4)?     at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:546
```

Comment: It's `Meteor.user()` with a lowercase u, not an uppercase U.

Comment: Isn't it `Meteor.user()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a look at the docs for [Meteor.user](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_user), you'll see it works everywhere *except* publish functions. You need to do:

```
var loggedInUser = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error your getting is because of the upper-case 'u' in `Meteor.User` it should be `Meteor.user`.

However, as David Weldon pointed out you'll need to use `Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId)` inside of publish functions.

For anyone else running into the error `Object #<Object> has no method 'user'` when trying to access `Meteor.user()` be sure you have the accounts-base package.